# 99 chips into more chips

Tags: logical-deduction, strategy, optimization

You are at a casino in Vegas and you have earned 99 chips by playing poker!

While you are checking out a slot machine, someone comes to you and congratulates you that you have a chance to make more chips by using your own chips into a strange four slot machine.

With this machine, you can put as many coins as you want into the four slots available and *pull the trigger only once* to make more coins but all four slots where you put your coins in the machine behave differently:

- One of them makes your coins **four times as many as before**!
- Another slot just **gives your coins back**.
- The last two slots **do not give your coins back** at all.

But you do not know which slot is which and you can take your coins back after pulling the trigger from somewhere else as a whole.

> At most how many coins can you guarantee to have at the end when playing with this machine?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Quick lower bound:**
If you were to

> Evenly divide the chips between the four slots (24 in each, with 3 left over), you would get 96 from one, 24 from another, and 0 from the others, for a guaranteed 123 chips in the end.

Comment: I think this would have to be the answer, as there is no probability or uncertainty involved in evenly dividing your chips, and the questions asks how many you can GUARANTEE to have at the end. Any other option seems to rely on odds.

Comment: A quick script verifies @MisterB is correct.  This is not only the lower bound, it is the upper bound that can be guaranteed.

Comment: Isn't this the upper bound for a guarantee, but the lower bound guarantee would actually be 99? (just walk away without any action?)

Comment: @APrough I initially just posted this as the most straightforward course of action, to show what more outlandish methods would have to beat to be the best.

Comment: To maybe simplify the logic: If you put one chip in every slot, you **lose** 4 chips but you also **gain** 5 chips (4+1+0+0). In other words, you're guaranteed to win 125% of your bet (though I'd semantically argue it's not really a bet then)

Comment: @APrough: No. The upper and lower bound refer to the answer to the question. Imagine that you start with a set of possible answers which are all the numbers. You can as you said apply a lower bound to the answer set of 99 and say the answer is at least 99 but you can also apply the above logic and say the answer is greater than or equal to 123. This answer doesn't *prove* that you can't get 150 or 200 by some clever method so it is not proving an upper bound in any way.

Comment: @Chris - I was looking at it as lower bound = the lowest amount I can guarantee to have, which is 99 (I cannot reliably say that I will lose money).  The upper bound would be as above, because that is the highest number you can guarantee to walk away with.

Comment: @APrough: Yup. I see where you are coming from, I was just trying to explain why the OP was using the terminology that they were.